# Entity drafts in Shopware

Tags: shopware

I noticed Shopware creates a 'draft' order entity every time when I visit a corresponding page in the admin panel. In the database this draft has the same `id` as original entity but different `version_id`. When I leave the entity page, Shopware removes that draft row from the database.

As the same, draft entities do not appear for product or category chapters.

Could you please explain me how this feature works and how it can impact related extended entities? I found only the brief explanation at https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/versioning-entities.html but do not understand how to control this process. Is it possible to deactivate this versioning at all?

I am using Shopware 6.5.8.3